# How get post #3 in a loop in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

How can I take data from certain posts when running a Jekyll cycle?
For example, I need post number 3.

Here's my loop:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
   <h2><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: just use `paginator.posts.3`

Comment: How then to create a condition in a loop like this:

If post = 3, then the action

If post = 4, then another action

Comment: If by "post number 3" you mean the 3rd item then `{% if forloop.index == 3 %}` should work. If `number` is a post attribute, try `{% if post.number == 3 %}`

Comment: Thank you! exactly what is needed!